# Locations of Geodetic Survey Benchmarks in Ontario?

Tags: data, canada

Does anyone know where I can find a list of geodetic benchmark locations for Ontario? (If a list even exists that is...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also available at Geobase Canada (Geodetic Network): http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/data/geod/index.html

Comment: Geobase is closed and the portal it redirects too doesn't return anything useful. Interactive map selection now at http://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/passive-passif.php?locale=en, look for "Passive Control Network". Haven't found a bulk download location yet.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can download it from Natural Resources Canada, but you will need to apply for a login (free): http://www.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/online_data_e.php

Apparently [GeoBase](http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/data/geod/index.html) provides them as grouped shapefiles based on your selected location, but I'm not entirely sure if it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find this site quite handy (I use it quite a bit.) This page has a list of benchmarks that are in and around Toronto and Ottawa. If you click on them you will get a data sheet similar to what NGS gives you.

http://www.waymarking.com/cat/details.aspx?f=1&guid=ebb67127-d531-4798-9d17-c6b77f235c49

This page (http://www.waymarking.com/cat/details.aspx?f=1&guid=ebb67127-d531-4798-9d17-c6b77f235c49&exp=True) also has a list of other sources of benchmarks in CA.

> Description: Canadian Benchmarks will include several types of
>   permanently fixed survey markers, monuments or other devices that are
>   used for taking accurate measurements within Canada.
>
> Expanded Description: From the Canadian Spatial Reference System's
>   online database the following benchmarks will be in this category:
>
> Canadian Base Network (NAD83CSRS) - 154 Total Stations
>   Special
>   Purpose 3-D Network (NAD83CSRS) - 3,082 Total Stations
>   Horizontal
>   Control Network 2-D (NAD83) - 25,677 Total Stations
>   Primary Vertical
>   Control Network (CGVD28) - 81,301 Total Stations
>   Canadian Gravity
>   Standardization Net (CGSN) - 5,737 Total Stations
>
> Other Databases
>
> Geological Survey of Canada Coastal Monitoring (GSC) - ? Total
>   Stations  TWL Regional Station Benchmark Database  MASCOT (BC
>   database) has a huge number of benchmarks that overlap existing
>   databases. This will need to be resolved before their types can be
>   setup.  COSINE (ON) also has a large database. I have not yet even
>   looked at this one.
>
> Canada-US Boundary Markers - The entire border has various types of
>   markers delineating the location of the international boundary. Some
>   of these markers are found in the CSRS database while others are not.
>   At the present time there is no special category for them. Perhaps
>   there should be as they are both US and Canada based benchmarks. For
>   more information visit the International Boundary Commission

And finally a forum post that I found talking about Canadian Benchmarks you may find interesting.

http://forums.groundspeak.com/GC/index.php?showtopic=80815