# Seeking list of geodetic benchmark locations for all of Canada?

Tags: data, land-survey, canada, triangulation-survey, benchmark

Does anyone know where I can find a list of geodetic benchmark locations for all of Canada?

I am looking for a few specific control monuments in Arctic Canada with accurate coordinates

Comment: Canadian Active Control System points seem like the modern equivalent of geodetic benchmarks (you can download data [here](https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/cacs-scca.php)). "The Canadian Active Control System (CACS) consists of unattended tracking stations, referred to as Active Control Points (ACPs), equipped with a high precision dual frequency GNSS receiver and an atomic frequency standard, which continuously record carrier phase and pseudorange measurements for all GNSS satellites within station view."

Comment: Where have you looked already?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this, but Canada wide since I am looking for a few specific control monuments in northern canada: http://www.gisapplication.lrc.gov.on.ca/cosineONT/Index.html?site=cosine&viewer=OntarioViewer&locale=en-US

Comment: I also found this website but the search tools don't seem to work very well. http://www.waymarking.com/cat/details.aspx?f=1&guid=ebb67127-d531-4798-9d17-c6b77f235c49

Comment: apparently geocachers enjoy searching for geodetic benchmarks, so you may want to look at geocache websites

Comment: Answers that can be given as one weblink points to a question that's not very good to begin with. Also, maybe this would be better suited on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I found my answer here using a survey plan search: http://clss.nrcan.gc.ca/clss/plan/search-recherche

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:

[Passive Control Networks](http://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/passive-passif.php?locale=en)

Partly answered by [another GIS:SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/locations-of-geodetic-survey-benchmarks-in-ontario) Q&A.